# iPhone iOS7 app running on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, ios-universal-app

If I build an iPhone app with Xcode5 for iOS7, I get this transparent style regarding StatusBar. So far it is ok with me as long I run it on an iPhone. But if I run the same iPhone app on iPad, I see the upper part of the window is hidden. E.g. a NavBar is only half visible. Why this crazy behavior?
Am I not supposed to build an iPhone app anymore for iOS7 and get a ok result on an iPad? Or is the meaning it always should be universal apps from now on?

Comment: Move the nav bar down on the iPad storyboard.. done.

Comment: If I build it for iPhone only, I do not have a storyboard for iPad.

Comment: Make one then. If you want to support a universal application without having to do a 2x version of the iPhone storyboard, then just crank it out.

Comment: The case is that the apps I would like to transform to iOS7 style are not easy to remake with storyboard. They are big and complicated. I can just click the universal button but then I get many other disadvantages when it comes to window size and behavior when running them on iPad.